# Chern-Simons form of Euler class

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, chern-simons-theory

Consider the Euler class for curvature $F_{AB} = d\omega_{AB}+\omega_A^{~~~C}\wedge\omega_{CB}$ where $\omega$ is the spin-connection given by
$$\int_{\mathcal{M}} \epsilon^{ABCD}F_{AB} \wedge F_{CD} = \int_{\mathcal{M}}\star F^{CD}\wedge F_{CD}$$ where $\epsilon^{ABCD}F_{AB} = \star F^{CD}$. Now, I wish to find its Chern-Simon form. For that I expand one of the $F$'s in the above. $$\int_{\mathcal{M}}\star F^{CD}\wedge F_{CD} = \int_{\mathcal{M}}(d\omega_{AB}+\omega_A^{~~~C}\wedge\omega_{CB})\wedge \star F^{AB} \\= \int_{\partial\mathcal{M}}\omega_{AB}\wedge\star F^{AB}+ \int_{\mathcal{M}}\omega_{AB}\wedge d\star F^{AB}+ \int_{\mathcal{M}}\omega_A^{~~~C}\wedge\omega_{CB}\wedge \star F^{AB}$$
The first term in the last equality is the Chern-Simons form I am looking for but somehow the last two terms I do not seem to be able to find a way to cancel. Can someone provide any suggestions as to how to go about this? My expectation was that somehow the last two terms would combine to become $$\int_{\mathcal{M}}\omega_{AB}\wedge D\star F^{AB}$$ which vanishes by Bianchi identity. However,
$$\int_{\mathcal{M}}\omega_{AB}\wedge D\star F^{AB} \neq \int_{\mathcal{M}}\omega_{AB}\wedge d\star F^{AB} + \int_{\mathcal{M}}\omega_A^{~~~C}\wedge\omega_{CB}\wedge \star F^{AB} $$
Can someone help with this?

Edit: I have noticed that

$$\int_{\mathcal{M}}\omega_{AB}\wedge d\star F^{AB} + \int_{\mathcal{M}}\omega_A^{~~~C}\wedge\omega_{CB}\wedge \star F^{AB} \\= \int_{\mathcal{M}} \omega_{AB}\wedge\star d(\omega^{AC}\wedge\omega_C^{~~~~B}) + \int_{\mathcal{M}} \omega_A^{~~~C}\wedge\omega_{CB}\wedge\star d\omega^{AB} +\int_{\mathcal{M}} \omega_A^{~~~C}\wedge\omega_{CB}\wedge\star(\omega^{AD}\wedge\omega_D^{~~~~B})\\= \int_{\mathcal{M}}d(\star\omega_{AB}\wedge\omega^A_{~~C}\wedge\omega^{CB})+\int_{\mathcal{M}} \omega_A^{~~~C}\wedge\omega_{CB}\wedge\star(\omega^{AD}\wedge\omega_D^{~~~~B})\\ = \int_{\partial\mathcal{M}}\star\omega_{AB}\wedge\omega^A_{~~C}\wedge\omega^{CB}+\int_{\mathcal{M}} \omega_A^{~~~C}\wedge\omega_{CB}\wedge\star(\omega^{AD}\wedge\omega_D^{~~~~B})$$
where I have simply substituted for $F$ in the above. It seems that the last term will not vanish by any means. Does that mean the Euler-Class above doesn't have a corresponding Chern-Simons form? Can anyone comment on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Euler class in this Lorentz gauge gravity context is called the topological Gauss-Bonnet form.

However, rather than
$$
\int_{\mathcal{M}} \epsilon^{ABCD}F_{AB} \wedge F_{CD} = \int_{\partial\mathcal{M}}\omega_{AB}\wedge\star F^{AB} + \int_{\partial\mathcal{M}}\star\omega_{AB}\wedge\omega^A_{~~C}\wedge\omega^{CB}
$$
one is supposed to look for:
$$
\int_{\mathcal{M}} \epsilon^{ABCD}F_{AB} \wedge F_{CD} = \int_{\partial\mathcal{M}}\omega_{AB}\wedge\star F^{AB} -\frac{1}{3} \int_{\partial\mathcal{M}}\star\omega_{AB}\wedge\omega^A_{~~C}\wedge\omega^{CB} 
\\=\int_{\partial\mathcal{M}}\omega_{AB}\wedge\star (d\omega^{AB}+\frac{2}{3}\omega^A_{~~~C}\wedge\omega^{CB})
$$
The derivation in OP of
$$
\int_{\mathcal{M}} \omega_{AB}\wedge\star d(\omega^{AC}\wedge\omega_C^{~~~~B}) + \int_{\mathcal{M}} \omega_A^{~~~C}\wedge\omega_{CB}\wedge\star d\omega^{AB}= \int_{\mathcal{M}}d(\star\omega_{AB}\wedge\omega^A_{~~C}\wedge\omega^{CB})
$$
seems to be wrong. It should instead be
$$
\int_{\mathcal{M}} \omega_{AB}\wedge\star d(\omega^{AC}\wedge\omega_C^{~~~~B}) + \int_{\mathcal{M}} \omega_A^{~~~C}\wedge\omega_{CB}\wedge\star d\omega^{AB}= -\frac{1}{3}\int_{\mathcal{M}}d(\star\omega_{AB}\wedge\omega^A_{~~C}\wedge\omega^{CB})
$$
since you have to be mindful of the extra minus sign when you switch the order of Exterior product between one-forms such as $d$ and $\omega$.

---

Added note:

It seems that the manipulations of indices such $A/B/C/D$ and $\epsilon^{ABCD}$ ($\star$) operation could be at times confusing/daunting. There is actually a way to get rid of (or hide) these nuisances and do all the calculations in a much simplified/elegant way: all you have to do is write the spin connection one-form in terms of gamma operators (see reference [here](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0264-9381/8/11/018/meta))
$$
\omega = \frac{1}{4}\omega^{AB}\gamma_A\gamma_B
$$
Then a lot of formulations can be simplified. For instance, the 4-$\omega$ term can be rewritten as
$$
\omega_A^{~~~C}\wedge\omega_{CB}\wedge\star(\omega^{AD}\wedge\omega_D^{~~~~B})\sim Tr[\gamma_5 \omega \wedge\omega \wedge\omega \wedge\omega ]
$$
where $Tr[...]$ is the trace of gamma matrices, and $\gamma_5 = i\gamma_0\gamma_1\gamma_2\gamma_3$.
And the proof of it being identical to zero is straight forward, since:
$$
Tr[\gamma_5 \omega \wedge\omega \wedge\omega \wedge\omega ] 
\\= Tr[\gamma_5 \omega \wedge (\omega \wedge\omega \wedge\omega) ]
\\= Tr[\omega  \wedge \gamma_5(\omega \wedge\omega \wedge\omega) ]
\\= -Tr[\gamma_5  (\omega \wedge\omega \wedge\omega)\wedge \omega ]
\\= -Tr[\gamma_5 \omega \wedge\omega \wedge\omega \wedge\omega ]
$$
where we have used the fact that
$$
\gamma_5 \omega =  \omega \gamma_5
$$
and
$$
Tr[F\wedge G] = -Tr[G\wedge F]
$$
if both $F$ and $G$ are odd-forms.

Other identities could also be easily proved. For example:
$$
d(\star\omega_{AB}\wedge\omega^A_{~~C}\wedge\omega^{CB}) 
\\ \sim d(Tr[\gamma_5\omega\wedge\omega\wedge\omega])
$$
and
$$
d(Tr[\gamma_5\omega\wedge\omega\wedge\omega])
\\=Tr[d(\gamma_5\omega\wedge\omega\wedge\omega])]
\\=Tr[\gamma_5d\omega\wedge\omega\wedge\omega - \gamma_5\omega\wedge d(\omega\wedge\omega)]
\\=Tr[\gamma_5d\omega\wedge\omega\wedge\omega - \gamma_5\omega\wedge d\omega\wedge\omega + \gamma_5\omega\wedge\omega\wedge d\omega]
\\=3Tr[\gamma_5d\omega\wedge\omega\wedge\omega]
$$

I will leave you an exercise to prove that the cosmological constant term as shown below is NOT identical to zero (contrary to the 4-$\omega$ term being identically zero as proved above)

$$
CC  \sim  Tr[\gamma_5 e \wedge e  \wedge e  \wedge e  ]
$$
where $e= e^A \gamma_A$ is the veirbein/tetrad. Hint: $\gamma_5 e = -e \gamma_5 $

Comment: I would be very grateful if you can explain how you get the $-1/3$.

Comment: $\int_{\mathcal{M}} \omega_{AB}\wedge\star d(\omega^{AC}\wedge\omega_C^{~~~~B}) = -\frac{2}{3}\int_{\mathcal{M}}d(\star\omega_{AB}\wedge\omega^A_{~~C}\wedge\omega^{CB})$ and $\int_{\mathcal{M}} \omega_A^{~~~C}\wedge\omega_{CB}\wedge\star d\omega^{AB}= \frac{1}{3}\int_{\mathcal{M}}d(\star\omega_{AB}\wedge\omega^A_{~~C}\wedge\omega^{CB})$

Comment: To help you understand the mathematical manipulations, I have added a note to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have have figured out how it works. It was just a simple matter of expanding the components

$$\int_{\mathcal{M}} \omega_A^{~~~C}\wedge\omega_{CB}\wedge\star(\omega^{AD}\wedge\omega_D^{~~~~B}) = \int_{\mathcal{M}} \epsilon^{ABCD}\omega_A^{~~~E}\wedge\omega_{EB}\wedge\omega_{CF}\wedge\omega_{~~~~D}^{F}$$
If we look at
$$\omega_1^{~~~E}\wedge\omega_{E2}\wedge\omega_{3F}\wedge\omega_{~~~~4}^{F} =(\omega_1^{~~~3}\wedge\omega_{32}+\omega_1^{~~~4}\wedge\omega_{42})\wedge(\omega_{31}\wedge\omega_{~~~~4}^{1}+\omega_{32}\wedge\omega_{~~~~4}^{2}) = 0 $$
Therefore, the last term is zero by default. Hence, we then finally have

$$\int_{\mathcal{M}} \epsilon^{ABCD}F_{AB} \wedge F_{CD} = \int_{\partial\mathcal{M}}\omega_{AB}\wedge\star F^{AB} + \int_{\partial\mathcal{M}}\star\omega_{AB}\wedge\omega^A_{~~C}\wedge\omega^{CB}$$ which is what I was looking for.